# Can Google Docs filter docs shared with me into folders?

Tags: google-docs

So I'm a teacher and I want documents that students share with me (that will always include something like "Block 1--M. Smith--Research Paper") to be filtered into a Block 1 folder.

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Google documents doesn't include a feature like Gmail filters that automatically process incoming messages, but it could be extended through add-ons and Google Apps Script.

## Alternatives

[Google Apps for Education](https://www.google.com/edu/apps) includes [Google Classroom](https://www.google.com/edu/classroom) which help teachers to manage assignments and include features to help teachers to manage files submitted by students.

## References

[Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)